# Equivalent of double parens in sh

Tags: sh

In `bash` I might write

```
if (( 1 || 0 )); then 
    echo 1
else 
    echo 0
fi;
```

How do I evaluate

```
(( 1 || 0 ))
```

in `sh` (dealing with an awk system call)

---

Actual use case

```
// string 
s="(( 1 && 0 ))"

// scope is awk

awk '{ system("if "s"; then echo foo; else echo bar; fi"); }'
```

Comment: It depends on what other features of `(())` you are using. What's the actual check you want to perform?

Comment: And why can't you use the logic tests available in `awk`? Waiting to see your use case. Good luck!

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: That's still not an actual use case. Please give us some practical, real-world context. Where did you get `$s` from, and what might it actually contain? (Obviously it won't contain hardcoded constants.)

Comment: @PaulHodges I am motivating the issue of evaluating a numerical expression in awk's system call.  it should be doable...

Comment: *Can* doesn't always mean ***should***. If you can give us a more realistic example, we might be able to present you with VASTLY better options...

Comment: Why are you choosing a `bash` syntactic construct as your interchange format?

Comment: @chepner would love to choose something that works

Comment: @PaulHodges basically, I am evaluating a string conjunction generated by my `m4` scripts.  This is as a convenience only, not a production component; I have total control over how this conjunction is formed, and I chose `(( 0 && || etc))` because I figured I could get something to evaluate it.  But maybe there is a better way to construct this expression? Either way, it isn't very useful unless it is evaluated from a document, where I have captured the conjunction(s) using regular expressions.  I figured awk would get me there, but now I am using the `test` solution.

Comment: I'd have to see the expression in context to figure out how it is relevant.

Comment: @PaulHodges ok Paul, there is an accepted answer.  Why it could be useful to you is not my problem.

Comment: I'm here to learn. (And that attitude doesn't inspire people to help you for no reason in the future. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent to `(( ... ))` in `sh` is

```
test $(( ... )) -ne 0
```

Both `(( ... ))` and `$(( ... ))` accept the same expressions, and both `(( ... ))` and the above `test` command have a return status of `0` when the expression `...` has a non-zero value, and a return status of `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [expr](https://ss64.com/bash/expr.html).

```
$: if  expr 0 \| 1; then echo "one"; else echo "zero"; fi
1
one
$: if  expr 1 \| 0; then echo "one"; else echo "zero"; fi
1
one
```

You might want to manage the output of `expr` itself.

```
$: if  expr 0 \| 1 >/dev/null; then echo "one"; else echo "zero"; fi
one
```

Comment: note that the pipe character is used as an operator by `expr` here, so you have to quote it. You could also use `expr 0 '|' 1` if you like it better.